# unittest.py doesn't play well with trace.py - why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

Wow.  I found out tonight that Python unit tests written using the `unittest` module don't play well with coverage analysis under the `trace` module.  Here's the simplest possible unit test, in `foobar.py`:

```
import unittest

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

If I run this with `python foobar.py`, I get this output:

```
 .
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Great.  Now I want to perform coverage testing as well, so I run it again with `python -m trace --count -C . foobar.py`, but now I get this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

No, Python, it's not OK - you didn't run my test!  It seems as though running in the context of `trace` somehow gums up `unittest`'s test detection mechanism.  Here's the (insane) solution I came up with:

```
import unittest

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

class Insane(object):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    module = Insane()
    for k, v in locals().items():
        setattr(module, k, v)

    unittest.main(module)
```

This is basically a workaround that reifies the abstract, unnameable name of the top-level module by faking up a copy of it.  I can then pass that name to `unittest.main()` so as to sidestep whatever effect `trace` has on it.  No need to show you the output; it looks just like the successful example above.

So, I have two questions:

1. What is going on here?  Why does `trace` screw things up for `unittest`?
2. Is there an easier and/or less insane way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simpler workaround is to pass the name of the module explicitly to `unittest.main`:

```
import unittest

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(module='foobar')
```

`trace` messes up test discovery in `unittest` because of how `trace` loads the module it is running. `trace` reads the module source code, compiles it, and executes it in a context with a `__name__` global set to `'__main__'`. This is enough to make most modules behave as if they were called as the main module, but doesn't actually change the module which is registered as `__main__` in the Python interpreter. When `unittest` asks for the `__main__` module to scan for test cases, it actually gets the `trace` module called from the command line, which of course doesn't contain the unit tests.

`coverage.py` takes a different approach of actually replacing which module is called `__main__` in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  I just need to tell the testing module what its own (file)name is and it works like a charm, both by itself and under trace.py.

Comment: BTW: trying to use cProfile and unittest with `python -m cProfile [some_test_file.py]` has the same problem, and the same solution: `unittest.main(module='tests')`. Search engines didn't find anything specific to cProfile, so adding a comment to try to help searching.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `trace` doesn't work properly, but [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage) does:

```
$ coverage run foobar.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
$ coverage report
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------
foobar       6      0   100%
```

Comment: I like coverage.py, but I switched to trace.py because I needed the *.cover files it generates (for automated coverage analysis carried out by CDash).  Is there a way to get coverage.py to emit these files?

Comment: I don't know what's in a .cover file, but it couldn't be that hard to make them from the data coverage.py collects.  Get in touch over email so we can talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Theran's answer but there were some catches with it, on Python 3.6 at least:

if I ran `foobar.py` that went fine, but if I ran `foobar.py Sometestclass`, to execute only `Sometestclass`, trace did not pick that up and ran all tests anyway.

My workaround was to specify defaultTest, when appropriate:

remember that unittest usually are run as

`python foobar.py <-flags and options> <TestClass.testmethod>` so targeted test is always the last arg, unless it's a unittest option, in which case it starts with `-`.  or it's the foobar.py file itself.

```
    lastarg = sys.argv[-1]
    #not a flag, not foobar.py either...
    if not lastarg.startswith("-") and not lastarg.endswith(".py"):
        defaultTest = lastarg
    else:
        defaultTest = None

    unittest.main(module=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0], defaultTest=defaultTest)
```

anyway, now trace only executes the desired tests, or all of them if I don't specify otherwise.