# Can other extensions (besides .py .pyc .pyo) be recognized as Python modules?

Tags: python-3.x, trace, coverage.py, test-coverage

I have a few test files residing in `test/` directory which has an `__init__.py` file. The test files are basically Python files but have the extension as .thpy (Python test files). Each of these tests internally use `unittest`.

For code coverage purposes, I'm using the `trace` module. `coverage.py`, unfortunately would have been ideal but at this time, doesn't give information on the number of line hits per line.

`unittest` and `trace` are not really compatible. [unittest.py doesn't play well with trace.py - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691509/unittest-py-doesnt-play-well-with-trace-py-why)

For example: I have a file name `cluster_ha.thpy`. From the solution given for the above question, I need to mention `module='cluster_ha'` inside `cluster_ha.thpy` but because of the extension, Python doesn't look at it as a Python module.

Is there any way to get around this? Is there a hack that can make other extensions to be considered as a Python module? Or perhaps, there's another module out there which can help me get code coverage?

Comment: How are you running the tests? One file at a time with the .thpy file on the command line?  This seems needlessly odd.  Just rename your files to .py, and let the tools do their jobs.

Comment: I run the tests as `python -m trace -c -m -C cov_dir/ test_script.thpy`. The reason I'm not renaming the files as .py is because .py extension files don't have permission to run on the test machines. I don't know why they don't or who put in that configuration but it's just .thpy (Python tests) or .thpl (Perl tests) which can run.